# Cannot deploy report type on Group Member object

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-report-type, deployment-error

I have created a report type on the Group Member object in a scratch org and pulled it into source control. When I attempt to push it to another scratch org, I get the following error:

> "GroupMember-QueuePublicGroupMembership.Id reference value: path -
> Could not find table for path, known paths are [GroupMember]"

How can I get this to deploy successfully? I have not hit this error before with any other objects and Googling has not resulted in any useful leads. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is the report type metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportType xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <baseObject>GroupMember</baseObject>
    <category>other</category>
    <deployed>true</deployed>
    <description>This custom report type should be used to create reports on public group memberships</description>
    <label>Public Group Membership</label>
    <sections>
        <columns>
            <checkedByDefault>false</checkedByDefault>
            <field>Id</field>
            <table>GroupMember-QueuePublicGroupMembership</table>
        </columns>
        <columns>
            <checkedByDefault>false</checkedByDefault>
            <field>Group</field>
            <table>GroupMember-QueuePublicGroupMembership</table>
        </columns>
        <columns>
            <checkedByDefault>false</checkedByDefault>
            <field>GroupMember-User</field>
            <table>GroupMember-QueuePublicGroupMembership</table>
        </columns>
        <columns>
            <checkedByDefault>false</checkedByDefault>
            <field>GroupMember-Group</field>
            <table>GroupMember-QueuePublicGroupMembership</table>
        </columns>
        <masterLabel>Group Member</masterLabel>
    </sections>
</ReportType>
```

And the sfdx command:

```
sf project deploy start --target-org review-feature --wait 20 --manifest manifest/package.xml --ignore-conflicts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is related to [Known issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000sv8Oh/unable-to-deploy-group-member-custom-report-type) tagged to `#W-14225126` that the Salesforce R&D team is already looking into.

There is no ETA for the fix at the moment. You can subscribe to the known issue so that you can get notified of the progress and fix.

At the moment, there is no workaround. Please create the Group member report type manually in the target org.

Comment: That explains it. Frustrating, but I will wait for a resolution. Thank you!